# Docker hostname not working

Tags: docker

```
docker run -d -v /srv/dockervolume/openssh-git/srv:/srv --name node-basickarl -h node-basickarl basickarl/node-basickarl
```

ping:

```
root@domain:/srv/dockervolume/haproxy/etc/haproxy# ping node-basickarl
ping: unknown host node-basickarl
```

It works when I ping the ipv4 address though. Why isn't hostname working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error `--name node-basickarl` should be `--name=node-basickarl`

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers would need to create DNS entries in either your local DNS server or your /etc/hosts file in order to be reachable via hostname. They don't do this by default.

Depending on what you're doing, manually creating an entry for the container in your hosts file might be the simplest solution.

This post lists a couple alternative options:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149501/how-to-reach-docker-containers-by-name-instead-of-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the image: https://hub.docker.com/r/basickarl/node/?  Try running this command:

```
docker run -d -v /srv/dockervolume/openssh-git/srv:/srv --name node-basickarl basickarl/node
```